# XPath - get a button inside another element with class

Tags: xpath

I need to find a button element using XPath. The problem is, the button has no unique identifier like Id or name, but is located inside another element which has a unique class (i.e. a class that no other element on page uses). I know how to get to that element and identify it by class but I don't know how to access the button inside that element.

```
.//mat-header-cell[@class='mat-header-cell cdk-column-delete mat-column-delete ng-star-inserted']
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION I FOUND:**

Just added '//button' to the end of xpath and it works now!

```
.//mat-header-cell[@class='mat-header-cell cdk-column-delete mat-column-delete ng-star-inserted']//button
```